# How not to wait for stability in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

I have an element with a CSS animation that makes it bounce a little. My Playwright test times out because the element never becomes stable. Its bounding box keeps changing because of the animation.

I could disable the animation for the tests as a workaround. But I wonder if it's possible to disable the auto-waiting for stability instead?

Comment: Puppeteer doesn't usually wait for animations. Can you show the page or a [mcve] of the animation we're dealing with here? How are you selecting that element? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Did you mean Playwright?

Comment: @ggorlen All good, no problem, I figured you were but just wanted to ensure we were talking about the same tool. It looks like Playwright does actually wait for the animation/bounding box stability before doing actions on elements: https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability#stable

Comment: Oh, wow. It's one too clever for me. I'm too used to Puppeteer which does very little stability checking like this and is generally less "smart" (maybe a feature?).

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. Yeah, one could definitely argue both for and against the “smart”ness ha ha.